# Search with multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, sorting, search

I am currently working on a search for a website and I am stuck with a problem, which doesn't even seem that hard to solve. I'm just not able to figure the solution out myself.

**Situation:** In the current state of my search I can sort the events to dates (I can select *October* for instance and it will only show the events which happen during october), for categories (The events each have categories) and even search text. Now when I select october as a month and festival as a category, I get all events occuring in october AND all festivals. I want only the festivals which occur in october. Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

This is what I've got so far:

```
var validEvents = new List<Item>();
var allEvents = ((LinkField)this.controlItem.Fields["Event Container"]).TargetItem.Children.ToList(); // getting the events

if (this.ddlMonths.SelectedIndex != 0 || this.ddlCategories.SelectedIndex != 0 || this.searchQuery.Text != string.Empty)
{
    foreach (var currentEvent in allEvents)
    {
        var isValid = false;

        // 1. Check for months
        if (this.ddlMonths.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            // .. validation if event should be displayed

            if (startDate <= monthDates[1].Date && endDate >= monthDates[0].Date)
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        // 2. Check for categories
        if (this.ddlCategories.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventCategory in ((MultilistField) currentEvent.Fields["Categories"]).GetItems())
            {
                if (eventCategory["Category"].ToLower() == this.ddlCategories.SelectedValue.ToLower())
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // 3. Check for search query
        if (this.searchQuery.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            var searchText = this.searchQuery.Text;

            if (currentEvent["Title"].Contains(searchText) || currentEvent["Text"].Contains(searchText))
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        if (isValid)
        {
            validEvents.Add(currentEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Following you code, you should make 3 list for the 3 filters you have, then merge the 3 in the final list wich will contains only the same elements in the 3 lists. This isn't very optimal but it's a simple solution.

Comment: What does your question have to do with sorting? I don't see the point of that tag. As far as the question you asked goes, IMHO you're going about it all wrong. First, if you want to write the whole search out as a single loop, you can, but your loop is too complicated. Get rid of `isValid` and just `continue` on any condition that would _exclude_ an item. Any item that survives to the bottom of the loop can be included. But really, this type of thing is what LINQ is for. You should do some research on the built-in C#/.NET features to support exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: Alright @PeterDuniho, I'll have a look into that

Comment: @PeterDuniho Your idea to work with continue actually works. Thank you for that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ you can combine search conditions as follows

```
var allEvents = ...;

IEnumerable<Item> events = allEvents;

if (ddlMonths.SelectedIndex != 0)
    events = events.Where(condition1);

if (ddlCategories.SelectedIndex != 0)
    events = events.Where(condition2);

if (searchQuery.Text != string.Empty)
    events = events.Where(condition3);

var validEvents = events.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put

```
var isValid = true;
```

in line 8, then if any of the conditions is NOT met set it to `false`. And also skip any following check if `isValid` is already `false`.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT - Complete code:**

```
var validEvents = new List<Item>();
var allEvents = ((LinkField)this.controlItem.Fields["Event Container"]).TargetItem.Children.ToList(); // getting the events

if (this.ddlMonths.SelectedIndex != 0 || this.ddlCategories.SelectedIndex != 0 || this.searchQuery.Text != string.Empty)
{
    foreach (var currentEvent in allEvents)
    {
        var isValid = true;

        // 1. Check for months
        if (this.ddlMonths.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            // .. validation if event should be displayed

            if (!(isValid && startDate <= monthDates[1].Date && endDate >= monthDates[0].Date))
            {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }

        // 2. Check for categories
        if (this.ddlCategories.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventCategory in ((MultilistField) currentEvent.Fields["Categories"]).GetItems())
            {
                if (!(isValid && eventCategory["Category"].ToLower() == this.ddlCategories.SelectedValue.ToLower()))
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // 3. Check for search query
        if (this.searchQuery.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            var searchText = this.searchQuery.Text;

            if (!(isValid && currentEvent["Title"].Contains(searchText) || currentEvent["Text"].Contains(searchText)))
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        if (isValid)
        {
            validEvents.Add(currentEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't work for me. Still get events which don't meet my category. But I have an idea on how I could solve it! I'll try @Raskayu 's solution. Thanks anyways :)